# Calculating BMI (Body Mass Index)

Tags: soft-question, applications

If I'm given the following values:

Weight = 15st 9lbs
Height = 5.8 ft

If we want to calculate the `BMI`, would it be: `33.30`?

And, in the final result we do NOT put any units, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually, BMIs are quoted as if it they were unitless, but technically they're in kg/m².

Comment: Height is 5.8 meters?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=bmi+calculator

Comment: @Gortaur,Have you ever see person $5.8$ meters tall ?

Comment: Your calculation is correct: since BMI has units of $\textrm{kg/m}^2$ you first need to convert your weight to kg and your height to metres before computing BMI as $\textrm{weight/height}^2$. As Henning says, usually people don't quote units, but they probably should.

Comment: @Gortaur,maybe height is in ft

Comment: @all downvoters: Please remember that this site is explicitly a **"Q&A for people studying math at any level"**

Comment: @t.b. The fact that this is googlable applies to any level and this question comes immediately after another with the same issue. Note that the OP did not ask anything about the way to calculate it, just if the result is correct and this is exactly information easily available in a google search.

Comment: @Phira: yes, I basically agree with that. Still I don't think that it merits -3 which it had when I started composing this.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to convert to metric units, or insert a constant as shown in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index).  BMI is mass (kg)/height (m)^2